# How to get the thumbnail image of different files?

Tags: java, image, swing, awt, thumbnails

I would like to get the thumbnail image of different files. It can be an image or a music or .docx document. I have made a code that gives me a very small image of that file type and not the actual file content. For example all images have the same icon. But in windows it shows the image as thumbnail or a picture of the first page of PDF file.

Here is my working code that shows a 32 x 32 image of the general icon of each format.

```
File file = new File("D:/Desktop/image.jpg");
Icon ico = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(file);
JLabel image = new JLabel();
image.setIcon(ico);
panel.add(image);
```

[image]

Any idea how to get the bigger specified icons for each file instead of the general ones?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a "Windows" feature, its a Windows Exporer feature. Open up any application (like Eclipse or Word) and from there open a file browser. You'll see that all of the icons are what you'd get from FileSystemView

Comment: Off-top: Since you already tagged your question with `java` there is no need to repeat that in your title.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Thanks for your comment. Is there any way I can do this kinda feature in a software. I do not know what kinda file it will be deal with, but it should follow the same way as Windows Exproper does ?

Answer (score 0):

For images you need to do following.

```
ImageIcon icn = new ImageIcon(new File("D:/Desktop/image.jpg"));
Image resized = icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(resized));
```

Some libs (IcePDF for example) can also convert pages of PDF files to images, so you can use the same approach.

Comment: Thanks, The software I am working on is a general file explorer, so I wont know what formats will the software deal with. I was looking for a general way. Like what windows explorer did.

Comment: @Dan I think explorer uses native Windows API which java cannot acces without native C/C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can follow what Windows explorer did is having a file type/content parser.
Unless windows does not have a PDF/word/Image explorer/processor, It cannot generate the thumbnail image  containing (for e.g.) first page in PDF files. Its just that commonly used processor comes bundled with Windows.

Getting back to you question of having thumbnails, You can do is extract extension of the file being explored and have Images saved (of that type) which will be shown as thumbnail (but not the actual content). Though, Images can be "thumbnail"ed easily as suggested in above answer. So, you can use that. For unknown file types, you could use some generic icon.

I don't think, an explorer which "reads" PDF/Word/Images etc. all in one will just be an explorer app.